How can I join this head model to the body without losing detail?
I’ve been working on this model for the past two weeks and am finally ready to merge the body to the head, however, using remesh (even at the lowest voxel size) would absolutely decimate any details on the face. Any alternate methods? 

You could join them and then try to use dynamic topology to "remesh" them at only the seam where they intersect. But I have a feeling that will be not very clean. I think that ultimately Join -> QuadRemesh -> Multiresolution -> Shrinkwrap to original joined mesh is the best bet. It's called reprojecting in Zbrush, this is basically that technique.

The problem with that method is that Quad remesh won’t work on a non manifold mesh, and in my case, my mesh in extremely non manifold haha

Then it looks like its manual retopology for you :D.

I don’t mind manual re topology at all, I’m just hoping the transition between the neck and body will still look smooth and natural.

If you retopologize and then reproject you might have to smooth things out  a bit but it should be manageable.
